# Using Producer methods (CDI 2.0) in Java SE

Tags: java, cdi

I am trying to write a simple example of using a Producer Method in Java SE with CDI 2.0 but run into an `Unsatisfied dependencies` issue.

Here is the producer:

```
private Random ran = new Random();

@Produces
private List<Integer> get() {
    return new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
        add(ran.nextInt(100));
        add(ran.nextInt(100));
    }};
}
```

and here is the injection point:

```
public class RandomNumberService {

    @Inject
    private List<Integer> randomNumber;

    public void print(){
        System.out.println(randomNumber);
    }

}
```

I am running the example by bootstrapping like so:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    SeContainer container = SeContainerInitializer
                    .newInstance()
                    .initialize();
    container.select(RandomNumberService.class).get().print();
    container.close();
}
```

I have a beans.xml file.

The exception is:

Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type List with qualifiers @Default at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private com.XXXX.randomNumber at com.XXXX.RandomNumberService.randomNumber(RandomNumberService.java:0)

I have tried using @Inject to inject beans and this works without issue so I know that the basic set up is OK. Also, I have tried to use the concrete type ArrayList rather that List and the same result.

Any help would be most appreciated.

In response to answers I have tried.

I tried: @Inject @Any private Instance> randomNumber;

The same error occurs. Also I have tried with a primitive type and a wrapper and I get the same response.

The same result when I produce a POJO.

```
@Produces
@Ford
public Car makeCar(){
    return new Car();
}

@Inject @Ford
private Car car;
```

I am beginning to suspect that the issue lies with the configuration of the SeContainer.

Comment: Using an exact copy of your code in a new maven project, weld-se-core 3.0.2-Final as a dependency and an empty beans.xml in resources/META-INF, the code works perfectly for me. Thus, there must be some other problem, probably somehow connected to the project setup. Which are your exact dependencies, do you have a beans.xml and what does it contain?

Comment: I suppose the beans with producers are *not* discovered. I am not sure what does your `beans.xml` look like and what (if any) bean discovery mode it declares, but default one is annotated. In that case, only classes with bean defining annotations will be discovered. Try adding some scope on the classes defining producers (E.g. `@ApplicationScoped`).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
@Any
@Inject
private Instance<Integer> randomNumber;
```

Once [`Instance`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/enterprise/inject/Instance.html) implements [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html?is-external=true), you will be able to iterate over the values.